CSS Flex - Alinhar imagem aos textos
Quero alinhar a imagem aos textos lateralmente de forma que a tag  fique lateralmente ao topo da imagem conforme a linha vermelha na imagem e a tag  fique abaixo do  conforme a linha verde.
Imagem de Exemplo


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 58px;
  list-style: none;
  padding-right: 100px;
}

ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#logo {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}

#pena {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Imagem ao lado do Texto</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="page">
    <nav>
      <img id="logo" src="https://img.freepik.com/vetores-gratis/vetor-de-gradiente-de-logotipo-colorido-de-passaro_343694-1365.jpg?w=740&t=st=1713647597~exp=1713648197~hmac=ce245055440c04c9ecc070e07e58049a08ae317d20c709530101526d339e55b1" alt="Lorem Ipsum"
      />

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
      </ul>

    </nav>

    <main>
      <section>
        <img id="pena" src="https://img.freepik.com/vetores-gratis/modelo-de-design-de-caneta-de-pena-gradiente_23-2149837194.jpg?w=740&t=st=1713648608~exp=1713649208~hmac=e9c8d485788179404da1202093ae7175d8c2391acaf0cc43247710213b57eed8" alt="uma pena" />

        <h1>Este e uma pena colorida!</h1>

        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus alias ipsa placeat aut eos ducimus expedita, posersimus consequuntur fuga reprehenderit et. Qui ex, velit ut pariatur aspernatur sit amet dolor.
        </p>
      </section>
    </main>

  </div>

</body>

</html>




quebrei a cabeça aqui e fiz da seguinte forma pra alinha <img> e <h1>,<p> envolvi os dois em uma div dai configurei tudo desta forma.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 58px;
  list-style: none;
  padding-right: 100px;
}

.ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#logo {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}

#pena {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.pagecentral {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px;
  padding: 10px;
}
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
</ul>

</nav>

<main>
  <section>
    <div class="pagecentral">
      <div class="imgpage">
        <img id="pena" src="https://img.freepik.com/vetores-gratis/modelo-de-design-de-caneta-de-pena-gradiente_23-2149837194.jpg?w=740&t=st=1713648608~exp=1713649208~hmac=e9c8d485788179404da1202093ae7175d8c2391acaf0cc43247710213b57eed8" alt="uma pena" />
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <h1>Este e uma pena colorida!</h1>

        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus alias ipsa placeat aut eos ducimus expedita, posersimus consequuntur fuga reprehenderit et. Qui ex, velit ut pariatur aspernatur sit amet dolor.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>

</div>




Augusto, fol mal esqueci de identar
